# c++ print/ build 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to build and print a 2d array but its showing up as empty when I try to print it out so there's an error somewhere but I cant find it. Can someone help? I added the code for initializing the array.

```
#ifndef MAZE_HPP_
#define MAZE_HPP_

#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Maze
{
public:
    Maze(int size);
    ~Maze() {}

    enum Direction { DOWN, RIGHT, UP, LEFT };

    // Implement the following functions:

    // read maze from file, find starting location
    void readFromFile(std::ifstream &f);

    // make a single step advancing toward the exit
    void step();

    // return true if the maze exit has been reached, false otherwise
    bool atExit();

    // set row and col to current position of 'x'
    void getCurrentPosition(int &row, int &col);

    //print function
    void printMaze();

    // You can add more functions if you like
private:
    // Private data and methods
    int size, rowX, colY;
    char matrix[30][30];
};


#endif /* MAZE_HPP_ */

void Maze::readFromFile(std::ifstream &f) {
    std::string line;
    int i, j;
    getline(f, line);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        getline(f, line);
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            matrix[j][i] = line[j];
        }
    }
    f.close();
}

void Maze::printMaze() {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << "";
            std::cout << "line";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run it? What is `size`? Is it initialized and how?

Comment: added the header file where its initialized

Comment: I don't see size initialized anywhere. Its value is undefined.

Comment: how would I initialize it? char matrix[30][30] = {0}; ?

Comment: Well, what is `size`? Its value needs to come from somewhere, right? You either enter it manually, or it is computed from your data somehow, etc. In this case it is the size of your `matrix` array.

Comment: size comes from the input file. It will be between 10 and 30. That's why the size is 30 for the array

Comment: matrix.length is the number of rows, matrix[0].length is the number of columns.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: Mate, in your printMaze you have a matrix, you are looping through its rows and columns. The variable `size` you have there is not initialized to anything, it is 0 by default. You need to assign it to something. In this case, the inner loop should have the number of columns in the matrix, the outer - the number of rows. There should be two variables instead of `size`, unless your matrix is always square. In your `readFromFile` method you also need to get `size` from somewhere. Probably you would want to read with `while` instead because you don't know this before you actually read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization does not matter here although it is good practice. Back to the problem: there can be several reasons 

1. You have passed zero or negative number for size in the constructor when you create a Maze object.

2. You have passed positive number for size but forgot to assign it to the size variable in the constructor.

If it enters into the loop in print function and shows the string "line" size times then it means it can not read anything from file.

It would be helpful if you send full code or at least the constructor.